# How can I print out the correct response based on input?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have a very simple problem that I'd like explained to me. I'm making a text adventure game and I'd like to be able to call another function inside a function so my code is organized better.

This is what I have that's working:

```
def displayIntro():
    print("You come to a crossroads on your trip home.")
    print ("You can go LEFT towards the DEMON FOREST or RIGHT to SKULL MOUNTAIN")
    print()

def choosePath(): 
    path = ""
    while path != "LEFT" and path != "RIGHT":
        path = input("Which path will you choose? LEFT or RIGHT? --> ")
    if path == "RIGHT":
        print("You take the path to SKULL MOUNTAIN.")
    elif path == "LEFT":
        print ("You take the path to the DEMON FOREST.")




displayIntro()
choosePath()
choosenPath()
```

But I'd like it to look something like this, but I don't know how to make it work:

```
def displayIntro():
    print("You come to a crossroads on your trip home.")
    print ("You can go LEFT towards the DEMON FOREST or RIGHT to SKULL MOUNTAIN")
    print()

def choosePath(): 
    path = ""
    while path != "LEFT" and path != "RIGHT":
        path = input("Which path will you choose? LEFT or RIGHT? --> ")
    return path


def checkPath(choosePath):

    if choosePath == "RIGHT":
        print("You take the path to SKULL MOUNTAIN.")
    elif choosePath == "LEFT": 
        print("You take the path to the DEMON FOREST.")



displayIntro()
choosePath()
checkPath()
```

Comment: `checkPath` takes a parameter, so: `checkPath(choosePath())`

Comment: Didn't you ask this [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39337309/2301450)?

Comment: @vaultah yep but for no reason it got down voted and not answered. It seems like a very simple thing that anybody who knows how to code would be able to answer in 5 seconds...

Comment: @DavidK A downvoted and not answered question means it's not *well-received by the community* and is not a reason to repost a duplicate. I would argue it's the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the return value of `choosePath` to `checkPath`.

```
checkPath(choosePath())
```

`checkPath` takes a parameter, so you need to supply a value. That value is the return value of `choosePath`, either "LEFT" or "RIGHT". Once you pass it in, the `checkPath` function will execute, checking the string and printing accordingly. Replace the `choosePath` and `checkPath` call with the above code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the return value of `choosePath()` to `checkPath()`. It should be:

```
path = choosePath()
checkPath(path)
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
checkPath(choosePath())
```